# android layout font

Tags: android, layout

I've got one list view (layout 1) with the code from `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`

This is the layout code from `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Now, with that layout I've created a similar layout with two differences. Added one more `TextView` and to those two TextView added `android:layout_weight`.
Here is the code from my new layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/text2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, when I create my list, the font size used on both of layouts is different. In layout 2 (the one I created), the font is bigger.

Here is a image:

[image]

How can I modify my second layout to be the exact same font size as list in `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`?

Comment: try this: android:textSize="8sp" add this line to both TextView

Comment: Hi. android:textSize="18sp" is approximately the same size but I believe this is a "forced" way to achieve the same. Still don't understand why the font size is different even  TextViews are defined the same way.